# BibTeX: Chicago style citation with same first authors

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style

I'm using TexShop (Tex Live 2010) on mac. I'm trying to use built-in Chicago citation style. But I found a bug when I try to cite the articles with the same first author, on the same year, with more than three co-authors but different ones.

Such as:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{my.bib}
@article{author1,
    author = {Author, F. and Author, S and Author, T},
    journal = {Journal A},
    title = {First Paper},
    year = {2000}}
@article{author2,
    author = {Author, F. and Author, S and Author, T and Author, F.},
    journal = {Journal B},
    title = {Second Paper},
    year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Some words \citep{author1, author2}.
\bibliographystyle{chicagoa} 
\bibliography{my}
\end{document}
```

Then got this result like "Author et al., 2000,?", 
while I want something like "Author et al., 2000a,b".

[image]

I guess this is a quite old known bug, so any comments are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to switch to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) which features an advanced mechanism for name/name list disambiguation. In the following example, I tried to emulate the behaviour of the `chicagoa` style with respect to name list citations; however, additional formatting tweaks may be advisable for the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib=true,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,
    uniquelist=false]{biblatex}

% Remove "In: " for articles (courtesy to Herbert)
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
  }{%
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author1,
    author = {Author, F. and Author, S and Author, T},
    journal = {Journal A},
    title = {First Paper},
    year = {2000}}
@article{author2,
    author = {Author, F. and Author, S and Author, T and Author, F.},
    journal = {Journal B},
    title = {Second Paper},
    year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some words \citep{author1, author2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]