# display only the first author of a piece in a citation call-out

Tags: citing, natbib

How do I have only the first author displayed in citation call-out, when using the `natbib` package?

There is a question similar to mine, which has never received an accepted answer:
[BibTeX: Chicago style citation with same first authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95185/bibtex-chicago-style-citation-with-same-first-authors)

Here is my preamble:

```
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
%...
\bibliography{references}
```

I use `natbib`, because it is the one mentioned in the wikibook on LaTeX:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/More_Bibliographies

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

But I feel I should maybe have used `biblatex`, but I can't get it to work at the moment, so I would like to stick with `natbib` if possible.

I tried to get `biblatex` to work with this preamble, but it fails, because my file `references.bib` contains the characters `@`, `%`, `<`, `>`, `×`, `ç` in some of the abstracts and author lists and the dates are malformed according to `biblatex` and it doesn't like entries such as `M3 = {...}`:

```
\usepackage[natbib,sorting=none,defernumbers=true,uniquelist=false,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\printbibliography
```

Comment: How are the remaining authors, for publications with two or more authors, supposed to be "shown" -- as "et al", or not at all? Please advise.

Comment: You need to run biber to get biblatex working. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: @Mico the remaining authors are to be shown as `et. al`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `plainnatsingle.bst`. (Do not directly edit an original file of the TeX distribution.)
- Open the file `plainnatsingle.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the bst file, locate the function `format.lab.names`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 1101.)
- In this function, replace the block

  ```
    #2 >
      { pop$ " et~al." * }
      { #2 <
          'skip$
          { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
              { " et~al." * }
              { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
            if$
          }  
        if$
      }
    if$
  ```

  with

  ```
    #1 >
      { pop$ " et~al." * }
      { pop$ "" * }
    if$
  ```

  In case you're curious what's going on: The second half of the function `format.lab.names` has been simplified drastically, to output "et~al." if the number of authors exceeds 1 -- and to output nothing otherwise.
- Save the file `plainnatsingle.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnatsingle}`. Then, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{a,
  author = "Annie Author", 
  title = "Thoughts", year = 3001 }
@misc{ab,
  author = "Annie Author and Brenda Buthor", 
  title = "Further Thoughts", year = 3002 }
@misc{abc,
  author = "Annie Author and Brenda Buthor and Carla Cuthor", 
  title = "Final Thoughts", year = 3003 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnatsingle}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{a}, \citet{ab}, \cite{abc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```